# how to use same function for different type of input?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

How to write Function That Take different  type of input ?

I want to write a function that take Victor as (array | object : {x , y});
But TypeScript Complain A lot!

I t

```js
function dist(x1,y1,x2 = 0,y2 = 0) { 
  if (x1?.constructor == Array && y1?.constructor == Array) {
    return dist(...x1, ...y1);
  }
  if (x1?.constructor == Object && y1?.constructor == Object) {
    return dist(x1.x, x1.y, y1.x, y1.y);
  }

  let a = x2 - x1,
    b = y2 - y1;
  return Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
}

console.log(
dist(0,0,1,1),
dist([0,0],[1,1]),
dist({x:0,y:0},{x:1,y:1})
)
```

hink This is not right way to do this. Also TypeScript not Happy at All.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Why don't you write a function that accepts a single type of input (the most common one) and then just convert your existing data to that format when required? That would make for a much cleaner looking function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe thats the thing you're looking for:

```
function divide(x: number, y: number): number;
function divide(str: string, y: number): string[];

function divide(x: any, y: number): any {
    if (typeof x == 'number') {
        return x / y;
    } else if (typeof x == 'string') {
        return [x.substring(0,y), x.substring(y)];
    }
}

let n: number = divide(6, 2);
console.log(n);
let s: string[] = divide("football",4);
console.log(s);
```

More to read: [overloading functions in JS](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/function-overloading.html)

Comment: I just dont want TS Complain. I am new in Typescript. How can I defined Array[] | Object( x , y ) type?  here -> ```function divide(x: number, y: number): number;```